# How to make a Split Button Menu Item scroll into view after this item has been selected?

Tags: javascript, yui

I've used YUI 2.6 for a while. Now, I realized the Split Button of YUI doesn't behave like the standard select html element. After an item is selected, when displaying the list again, it neither highlight or scroll that item into view at all. In the worst case, if I have 200 items, the user has selected the 100th item, when he/she wants to change his/her choice, he/she has to scroll from the beginning. It is not user-friendly at all. Unlike the standard select html element, it does highlight and scroll that item into view. Any idea is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that large numbers of items in the menu isn't a use case that the [split button menu](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example08.html) was designed to handle. Unlike a `select` input element users can't quickly filter to the option they would like to select using the keyboard. Think about if the initial item the user wanted to select was the 100th item - they'd also have to scroll from the beginning anyway.

Maybe there's a better approach to take for what you are trying to do given context of your problem. If you provide more details about what you are wanting to help the user achieve maybe others will have ideas on some different approaches.